# Bathroom Drain/Vent Design

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, drain-waste-vent

I have a new bathroom that I'm having trouble figuring out the drains for. Here are the specs:

- **Dimensions**: 11' x 5'
- **Construction**: 2x4 framing, raised foundation (decent crawlspace), 2 exterior walls (indicated in image with orange)
- **Fixtures**: (left to right) shower, toilet, lav sink
- **Existing plumbing**: 4" sewer line capped off under subfloor, 2" vent pipe capped off through roof
- **Location**: Los Angeles, CA

At first I imagined a simple wet vent system running a 2" vent up from the sink drain and through the roof, but then realized that I probably shouldn't cut a 2+" notch/bore an exterior wall top plate that is only 2x4. So my next thought was running a 2" vent up through the non-load bearing wall and the minimum size sink vent (1-1/4") and connecting them above the ceiling joists, before the vent header.

Another idea I had was I could run the 2" vent up from the sink, pop out of the exterior wall, and back in under the eave, then finally connect to the pipe jack in the roof. I have some C channel on the exterior already for A/C plumbing so it could be covered. Essentially it would going around the top plate, but I don't know if that would be up to code.

Here are some images to better explain the layout. Does anyone have any recommendations for a drain/vent system for this bathroom?
[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

And here is a drain layout I was imagining, but not sure if the venting works. Trying to minimize the hole size through the load bearing top plate:
[image: Text]